When can we just use the normal distribution properties?
I would like to know when we can use the normal distribution properties.
Example:
Suppose I am collecting some data points for some experiment. I then draw a histogram(I know that histograms can misinterpret the data, but for my question let it accurately represents the data collected).
Let the histogram represent the normal distribution looking shape(bell shaped). Also the median $\approx$ mode $\approx$ mean.
Does this mean that I can just assume that the normal distribution properties hold?-like 68% of the data lies within the first standard deviation, 95% within 2 standard deviations, etc...?

You could try performing a normality test such as Shapiro-Wilk, or you could try graphical methods such as a Q-Q plot to assess the normality of the data.

It depends on how much the histogram "looks like" a normal distribution. If it looks exactly like a normal distribution then it is a normal distribution and has all the properties of a normal distribution. But if it only looks kinda sorta like a normal distribution, it will only kinda sorta have  the properties  of a normal distribution.

Looking like normal is a bit vague. Median being equal to mean tells it's symmetric. Mode being equal to to mean tells it reaches it's peak at mean. These can be satisfied with other shapes that visually look like a bell. I therefore think one shouldn't expect them to satisfy normal distribution properties like standard deviation.

If you have finite amount of data it can be difficult to distinguish between a binomial distribution and a normal distribution.

If you have the data, you can see from the data how much of your sample is within 1 or 2 standard deviations of the mean.  That does not tell you about the population distribution, but might be suggestive.

There are many distractions which are "bell shaped" like but not normal at all (e.g. Cauchy). There are various tests to check normality, see comments above.
